# Clicking on a Button in a Pop-up should not close the button if the form in empty + Javascript/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using a pop-up SIGN-UP form. I am using Javasript/HTML/PHP. I want to keep the Form open if the fields are empty and Register Button is pressed. But in the current code, when I press on the Register Button, the pop-up gets closed irrespective of whether data is filled in. Need help.

Code that calls the Pop-up

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick ="document.getElementById('signup_popup').style.display='block'">SIGN UP</a>
```

Code inside the sign-up popup

```
//Code when the signupbtn is pressed

//Code if forms are filled
if( //Forms are filled){
} else{

 //What should be the code to keep the form open when data is not present in the form ?????? Please help

}


?>

<div id="signup_popup"> 
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="abc">Mobile Number:</div><input type="text"     name="mobile" placeholder="+91" value="" /></br>
        <div class="abc">Email Address:</div><input type="text" name="email_address"     placeholder="xyz@gmail.com" value="" /></br>
        <div class="abc">Password:</div><input type="password"     name="login_password" placeholder="password" value="" /></br>
        <div class="abc">Confirm Password:</div><input type="password"     name="confirm_login_password" placeholder="password" value="" /></br>
        <input id="signupbtn" type="submit" name="Signup" placeholder=""      value="SIGN UP" /></br>
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: The popup gets closed because you're sending the form, and with its `action` being blank, the browser simply reloads the page, making it look like the popup is turned invisible again. You need to assign an `onsubmit` handler to the form that calls `preventDefault()` on the submit event if the form isn't valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define function to check if the fields are filled and return its result to the input button onClick. (The alert ist only for demonstrations)

```js
function allDataSet(){
  if(document.getElementById('inputMobile').value == ""){ //  add more here
    alert("please fill in all fields!");
  return false;
  }
 return true;
  }
```

```html
<div id="signup_popup"> 
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="abc">Mobile Number:</div><input id="inputMobile" type="text"     name="mobile" placeholder="+91" value="" /></br>
        <div class="abc">Email Address:</div><input type="text" name="email_address"     placeholder="xyz@gmail.com" value="" /></br>
        <div class="abc">Password:</div><input type="password"     name="login_password" placeholder="password" value="" /></br>
        <div class="abc">Confirm Password:</div><input type="password"     name="confirm_login_password" placeholder="password" value="" /></br>
        <input id="signupbtn" type="submit" name="Signup" placeholder=""      value="SIGN UP" onclick="return allDataSet()"/></br>
    </form>

</div>
```